# Digitally signing word documents

Tags: c#, openxml, digital-signature, .net-7.0

When using the full .net framework, signing a word document was not hard. However, it seems like the helper classes (ex.: PackageDigitalSignatureManager) are not available in net core.  Can anyone reference any good recent article/post on how to digitally sign a docx with net 7.0?

thanks